# DataGridview Cells are not filled

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview, windows, cells

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= TimeSub; k++)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(FromDate); // hour
                    dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value = FromTime;
                    FromTime = FromTime + 1;
                } 
                FromDate=FromDate.AddDays(1);

            }
```

While I am executing this statement all the rows are filled correctly but the cells are not. Kindly help on this.

[image]

Comment: With what value you want to fill row ? Please specify question correctly

Comment: what is the use of i

Comment: I need to fill the column with Numeric Up Down values.

Ex: Every day fill the column between 20 - 23.
ie: 4/1/2017 -20
     4/1/2017 -21
     4/1/2017 -22
     4/1/2017 -23
     4/2/2017 -21
     4/2/2017 -22
      ...
      ...

Answer (score 1):

You are always looping from the first row in the second loop.
[Rows.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75kfezas(v=vs.110).aspx) retruns the new row index.

Try this instead:

```
var rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(FromDate); // hour
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = FromTime;
```